# Jupyter notebook with bibtex citations

Tags: ipython, bibtex, jupyter

I have a .ipynb file containing markdown text. I have a bibtex file called library.bib with all my references. I wish to cite one of these references in the Markdown cell.

I've found information on how to render this when I do nbconvert, but how can I have the references in my browser window in the raw ipynb format?

Comment: Matthias has pointed out my cite2c extension; this can display citations in the live notebook, but it doesn't work with bibtex. I hope to better integrate it with nbconvert in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://github.com/takluyver/cite2c which is a notebook extension.

Comment: Apparently doesn't work with bibtex. Besides perhaps uploading library file to zotero.

Answer (score 1):

[The Calico Document Tools extensions](http://jupyter.physics.brynmawr.edu/hub/dblank/public/Jupyter%20Help.ipynb#2.2-Document-Tools) supposedly offers BibTeX support. For Jupyter 4.x seems to need adaptations. See section [Notebook Extension Structure](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions#notebook-extension-structure) from README in the *ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions* repository on github.

Comment: There is a [Reference Guide](http://jupyter.cs.brynmawr.edu/hub/dblank/public/Jupyter%20Notebook%20Users%20Manual.ipynb#5.-Bibliographic-Support) for this extension.

Comment: Hi  @asm, is there any other source. This guide cannot access.